# How to replace the semi-colon with new line in html <td> of the particular model attribute content?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am displaying ${xyz.names} where xyz is model attribute object passed from spring controller. "names" is String having semi colons.
Want to replace semi-colons with new line, such as if names="abc;def;ghi", it should be displayed as

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Used below js code but didn't work:

```
:
:
<td id="data1">${xyz.names}</td>
:
:

<script>
var data1=document.getElementById("data1");
document.getElementById("data1").innerHTML = data1.replace(/;/g, '<br />');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using jstl and scriptlet. Couldn't achieve it using script.

```
<c:set var="v" value="${xyz.names}"/>   
<%String sites=(String)pageContext.getAttribute("v");  %>
<td><%  out.print(sites.replace(";", "<br>"));%></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added `.innerHTML` in the assignment statement and it works now.

```js
let data1 = document.getElementById("data1").innerHTML
document.getElementById("data1").innerHTML = data1.replace(/;/g, '<br />')
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="data1">abc;def;ghi</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: then you should replace it from the script before displaying it.